# How do I add gradient to an svg path from getwaves.io?

Tags: svg, gradient

I couldn't find this exact same question anywhere else but I would like to know how I can add gradient to an svg like this one below (from getwaves.io):

< svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
< path fill="#0099ff" fill-opacity="1.2" d="M0,192L60,197.3C120,203,240,213,360,186.7C480,160,600,96,720,112C840,128,960,224,1080,224C1200,224,1320,128,1380,80L1440,32L1440,0L1380,0C1320,0,1200,0,1080,0C960,0,840,0,720,0C600,0,480,0,360,0C240,0,120,0,60,0L0,0Z">

For now I have just "solved" it by taking the opposite curve I need and rendering the other part of the div the same color as my website, but I'm assuming there's a better way to do this?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Does [<linearGradient> on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient) sort out your issue?

Comment: I tried adding the defs part into the svg but for some reason I couldn't get it to work. I will try again later, I was pretty tired last night.

Do I need to remove the path fill if I want to do this? And do I style myGradient as normal in CSS? Sorry if these are stupid questions :) Thanks for helping!

Comment: You're just missing the <linearGradient>, its id attribute and that id referenced in the fill of the path. That will / should get you there.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll try it out when I get off work in a couple of hours!

Comment: Btw it worked :) Didn't know I had to add url(#GradientID) to the fill path. Thanks!

Comment: @codonoty what is gradient id? can you give an example.